# Spring Boot application port change works locally but not on AWS EC2

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, port

I have a Spring Boot backend application that by default runs on port 8080. I've changed the port to 8081 in the `application.properties` file and it works perfectly on my local machine. I can successfully access my application's endpoints, such as `http://localhost:8081/login/go`, using Postman.

However, when I deploy the same application to an AWS EC2 instance and try to access the same endpoint (replacing localhost with the EC2 instance's public IP, `http://16.163.58.122:8081/login/go`), I'm unable to reach it. There are no logs indicating that the server has received the request from Postman.

Interestingly, if I change the port back to 8080 and try to access the endpoint `http://16.163.58.122:8080/login/go`, I'm able to reach the server's login interface again.

And it seems that the security group permits 8081 port
[image]
Port seems not being used by any other process.
[image]
And I tried other different port, seems only 8080 can connect.
I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you deploying to AWS? Are yo using the embedded container or are you uploading a war file and use a standalone servlet container? If it is the latter the `server.*` properties are ignored as Spring Boot cannot control an external servlet container instance.

Comment: I am deploying my Spring Boot application to AWS by using a self-contained JAR file that includes an embedded servlet container, and running it using the java -jar command.

Comment: Do you see the application being started with port 8081? Or can you access it on 8080 when you set `server.port=8081`? Just to check if it gets overridden by something else.

Comment: I use `java -jar xxx.jar --server.port=8081` and it shows `Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''` in the log. But still can't connect neither 8080 nor 8081 using Postman. When I start the same jar package on my machine, 8080 and 8081 are both OK.

Comment: Then it must be something in the routing/firewall rules on AWS as the app starts and apparently nothing is overriding the port so it starts on the configured one.

Comment: Now I edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` and add 8081 to the list, and it works. Thanks for help